# How to overlap background image in a table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery to display list on hover but when i do so list hide behind image below it showing date. Suggestion plz

```
<style type="text/css">    
.calendar_date                    { font-family : Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size : 15px; color : #222222; }
a.calendar_date                    { color: #0000aa; text-decoration: none; }
a.calendar_date:hover            { color: #000080; text-decoration: underline; }

//.calendar_navigation            { font-family : Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size : 14px; color : #222222; }
//a.calendar_navigation            { color: #0000aa; text-decoration: none; }
//a.calendar_navigation:hover        { color: #000080; text-decoration: underline; }


.calendar_day                    { font-family : Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size : 12px; color : #222222; }
a.calendar_day                    { color: #0000aa; text-decoration: none; }
a.calendar_day:hover            { color: #000080; text-decoration: underline; }

.calendar_date_number            { font-family : Cursive,menu, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif,solid,bold; float:left; margin-left : 10px; color : #222222; }
a.calendar_date_number            { color: #0000aa; text-decoration: none; }
a.calendar_date_number:hover    { color: #000080; text-decoration: underline; }

.calendar_date_small                    { font-family : Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size : 12px; color : #222222;  }
a.calendar_date_small                    { color: #0000aa; text-decoration: none; }
a.calendar_date_small:hover            { color: #000080; text-decoration: underline; }

.calendar_navigation_small            { font-family : Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size : 12px; color : #222222; }
a.calendar_navigation_small            { color: #0000aa; text-decoration: none; }
a.calendar_navigation_small:hover        { color: #000080; text-decoration: underline; }

.calendar_day_small                    { font-family : Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size : 10px; color : #222222; }
a.calendar_day_small                    { color: #0000aa; text-decoration: none; }
a.calendar_day_small:hover            { color: #000080; text-decoration: underline; }

.calendar_date_number_small            { font-family : Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size : 9px; color : #222222; }
a.calendar_date_number_small            { color: #0000aa; text-decoration: none; }
a.calendar_date_number_small:hover    { color: #000080; text-decoration: underline; }

//table.rounded td         { -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; }
table.rounded5 td         { -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; }
//table.notrounded td         { -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px; }
table.rounded5     {background:url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat; height:300px;}
.dates_table     {background:url(images/box.jpg) no-repeat; height:45px; position:relative;}


.blank_day         {background:url(images/simple_box.jpg) no-repeat; height:45px}
//table.td.rounded5{background:url(images/box.jpg) no-repeat;}
.text                    { font-family : Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size : 13px; color : #222222; }
a.text                    { color: #0000aa; text-decoration: none; }
a.text:hover            { color: #222222; text-decoration: underline; }

td.calendar_entry_full {background:url("no.png") no-repeat center; color:#222222; }
.dropdown_list             {list-style: none; float:left; padding:0px;}                            



td#drop {
    //font-size: 1.2em;

    //background: url(../images/box.jpg) no-repeat;
}
td#drop ul li a:hover{
    /*background: url(topnav_hover.gif) no-repeat center top;*/
}
td#drop span#drop { /*--Drop down trigger styles--*/
    width: 10px;
    height: 5px;
    float: left;
    background: url(jquery%20example/dropdown_linkbg.gif) no-repeat center top;
}
td#drop span.subhover {background-position: center bottom; cursor: pointer;} /*--Hover effect for trigger--*/
td#drop ul.subnav {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute; /*--Important - Keeps subnav from affecting main navigation flow--*/
    background: #FFF;
    margin: -5px 0px 0px -4px; padding: 0;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 107px;
    border: 2px groove #CAD7F9;
    border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;

}
td#drop ul.subnav li{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    //border-top: 1px solid #252525; /*--Create bevel effect--*/
    //border-bottom: 1px solid #444; /*--Create bevel effect--*/
    clear: both;
    border:1px solid #CAD7F9;
    border-bottom:none;
}
html td#drop ul.subnav li a {
    float: left;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:center #FFF;
    padding-left: 30px;

}
html td#drop ul.subnav li a:hover { /*--Hover effect for subnav links--*/
    background:center #FFF;
    display:block;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: show some of your code and we will help you fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without jQuery and just use CSS. I'm using a background color but an image would have the same effect.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/strb2/

```
<table id="main">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>This is a list.</li>
                <li>This list has stuff.</li>
                <li>Look at this list.</li>
                <li>This list is sweet.</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS...

```
#main {
    background-color: #ccc;    
}
#main ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 15px;
}
#main:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

This is the best I can do without seeing your code. Another option, if you want to force an element (like a list) to appear above another element, is to try adding this CSS to your element...

```
#yourlist {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10; /* you can set this higher if needed */
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry guys but i'm not able to post jquery script because i have low reputation point. thanks!

Comment: wdm@ sir can i use #main {background image} instead of color?

Comment: @chetan yes, you can use #main { background-image: url(path/to/img.jpg); }

Comment: @wdm i have used button image in a calender showing date what i'm trying to do is when someone click on this button a drop-down list will appear where i will show time slot for an "APPOINTMENT" but sir when i do so drop-down list show behind image. i tried different properties like opacity visibility but can fix it. :-|

Comment: @wdm i tried sir but couldn't figure out whats wrong , when background image is absolute , drop-down list appear behind it and when i made background image relative then block of images below shift down according to length of the list , can u give me some demo or have you any idea where i'm going wrong...hmm ya like oracle site there is drop down list and it overlap content

Comment: @chetan I don't understand what you're doing. If you have one element (say a DIV) that contains a drop down list. If you set a background image on that DIV there is no reason that the list should appear behind it. Use the link in my previous comment to isolate the portion of code you are using that is causing the problem. That is the ONLY way I can help you here.